# Copy Files from Folders That Start with a Particular Name Using CMD or Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, cmd, command-line

I want to copy files from a particular path that is contained in multiple folders into another folder while maintaining the name of the parent folders. However, the name of the path is not very consistent. The only thing consistent is the starting characters of the folder names.

So I tried this:

```
Copy *\2.0*\2.2.1*\2.2.7*\ C:\Destination\*\
```

Of course, it did not work.

Any solution would be highly appreciated using cmd or Powershell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for /D %A in (".\2.0*") do for /D %B in ("%~A\2.2.1*") do for /D %C in ("%~B\2.2.7*") do md "C:\Destination\%~C" 2> nul & copy "%~C" "C:\Destination\%~C"` (directly executed in Command Prompt when being in the parent directory containing the `2.0*` folder)?

Comment: @aschipfl. Thanks. This worked. I also used this to develop other interesting ways of file transfer. What does this do " 2> nul &" precisely?

Comment: [`2> nul`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) suppresses error messages of `md` in case the directory to create already exists…

Answer (score 0):

The following command line ([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)) should do the trick:

```cmd
for /D %A in (".\2.0*") do for /D %B in ("%~A\2.2.1*") do for /D %C in ("%~B\2.2.7*") do md "C:\Destination\%~C" 2> nul & copy "%~C" "C:\Destination\%~C"
```

Here is the same as a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) with some explanatory remarks:

```cmd
rem /* Wildcards like `*` and `?` can only be used in the last part of a path,
rem    hence each directory level needs to be resolved on its own: */
for /D %%A in (".\2.0*") do (
    for /D %%B in ("%%~A\2.2.1*") do (
        for /D %%C in ("%%~B\2.2.7*") do (
            rem // Create found directory tree, suppress errors if already existing:
            md "C:\Destination\%%~C" 2> nul
            rem // Actually copy the contents of the source directory to the built path:
            copy "%%~C" "C:\Destination\%%~C"
        )
    )
)
```